# Foundation 5 - New <li> items now showing in existing dropdown buttons

Tags: zurb-foundation

When I add new list items to an existing dropdown button they do not show up on the front end. The dropdown just continues to show the original list items. All my caching systems are off and I cleared the cache locally, but I'm still getting the same issue. Anyone know what could be causing this?

```
<div class="sidebar-dropdown">
  <button data-dropdown="drop" aria-controls="drop", aria-expanded="false" class="large alert round button dropdown">Select Type</button>
  <br> 
  <ul id="drop" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown" role="menu" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1">
    <li><a href="http://www.cardpaymentoptions.com/best-merchant-accounts/#general">All-Purpose (USA)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.cardpaymentoptions.com/best-merchant-accounts/#mobile">Mobile</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.cardpaymentoptions.com/best-merchant-accounts/#ecommerce">E-Commerce</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.cardpaymentoptions.com/best-merchant-accounts/#general-can">All-Purpose (CAN)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.cardpaymentoptions.com/best-merchant-accounts/#pos">Tablet POS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.cardpaymentoptions.com/best-merchant-accounts/#high-risk">High Risk</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some sample code so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: If you look at the source for the upper right button on the following page, you will see a list item for "E-commerce" but it doesn't show on the live button: [link](http://www.cardpaymentoptions.com/credit-card-processors/first-data-review-complaints-and-rating/)

Comment: OK, but what code is inserting that `li`? If you post some relevant code here, people can help you more easily. Thanks

Comment: I'm adding the list items manually; however, when I add a new item, it doesn't appear on the live button. I'm not able to add code. I'm getting an error message saying that it's too many characters.

Comment: Just added code to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Foundation-generated dropdown needs to be refreshed when new content is added to it. This can be done by adding this to your javascript, which adds a listener to the dropdown element(s):

```
$(document).foundation('dropdown', 'reflow');
```

[See the docs for more info](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html)

Comment: Hi Chad, thank you very much. That makes complete sense. Can you tell me, should this snippet be added directly to the page source, or is there a specific Foundation JS file to which it should be added? I'm still a little bit of a newb on Javascript and JQuery.

Comment: As outlined [in the docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html), you could place that inside a `<script></script>` tag, just before `</body>`.

Comment: Thank you again for the response and the link to find this type of information in the documentation.

Comment: Great! If you found my answer to be a solution for you, please mark the answer as such. Thanks!